# Is there a function that $f^{-1}(x)=f'(x) $?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, derivatives

$$f^{-1}(x)=f'(x)   \forall x \in R$$
$R$ is a set of real  numbers.

I try to find it  or disprove that fact but I didn't make it.

Comment: Try functions of the form $f(x)=\alpha x^\beta$. By the way: See here   http://mathoverflow.net/questions/34052/function-satisfying-f-1-f/34095#34095

Comment: Is this the same as $f''(x)f(x)=1$ after differentiating? If so, then the answer is given by the exponential of the $erf$ function, which is complicated and not easy to derive.

Comment: Is $R$ *the* set of real numbers, or a subset of the reals?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is impossible if you want $f$ to be a bijection $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ (and if you don't want that, you have to explain what $f^{-1}$ means).  Indeed, if $f$ is a differentiable injection $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, it must be monotone by the intermediate value theorem.  This implies $f'$ is either always nonnegative or always nonpositive.  Suppose that $f'$ is always nonnegative (the other case is similar).  The identity $f'(x)=f^{-1}(x)$ then must fail whenever $x=f(y)$ for $y<0$.